# How can I stub/mock non-pointer member variables in C++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googlemock

Many websites on unit testing say to extract an interface and code to the interface (which makes sense), but that requires using polymorphism via pointers. Is it possible to accomplish this without pointers so I don't have to modify the production code? I would rather not use pointers and manage memory.

- Conditional compilation is allowed.
- I am specifically using gmock for my stubs/mocks.

Some things that I've researched are:

- Using references

  - involves writing special copy constructors or making it non-copyable
  - still have to manage memory with new/delete
  - not sure if this will cause unforseen problems down the line
- Creating via code-generation a collection of pointer-wrapper classes. The interface stays the same with a few added methods for testing.

  - seems like it would work but require upkeep
  - example of what I mean down below

**Please note that gmock mock objects are not copyable**, therefore I cannot constructor inject them. (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlemock/GD73UXjQowE/discussion)

## Problem Example

```
class Example
{
public:
   Example();
   ~Example();

private:
   // I want to stub out _foo.
   Dependency _foo;
};
```

## Pointer Wrapper Class Example

```
#ifndef UNIT_TEST
   Foo _foo;
#else
   PtrWrapFoo _foo;
#endif
```

**...**

```
_foo.setImpl(StubFoo *aStubFoo);
```

**...**

```
void PtrWrapFoo::doSomething()
{
   _impl->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: is modifying the code to use boost::shared_ptr<> an option in the production code? this hides the unpleasant parts of dealing with pointers for the most part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After careful consideration, I have decided to abandon the idea. It becomes too difficult to try and manage the circumstances in which the dependency should use a particular implementation (e.g. real, mock, fake), given the testing scenario.

All dependencies that need testing now have interfaces, which are memberless. My production code uses pointers for dependencies, which is a a reality I have to live with if I want testable code. I was persuaded to this notion after reading Roy Osherove's book, *The Art of Unit Testing*. My regular constructors instantiate the real, concrete class. I also have extra constructors/setters that are conditionally compiled for unit tests so I can properly set up dependencies by using stubs/mocks.

I have reduced my need to write extra code by using a tool to extract an interface from a class.

Overall, the new design is good and adequately sidesteps the problem of mocking non-pointer member variables with minimal overhead.

Comment: unfortunatelly that is something that C++ developers have to live with. I was grinding my teeths when I first started doing this. Looking at your comment you followed the Dependency Inversion principle and your code started to be a bit less coupled to the concrete classes so thats a good thing!

Comment: If money is of no issue you could use a commercial mocking framework.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have implemented `Dependency` in a separate compilation unit and linked against that instead of the original.

This is what Michael Feathers calls a [Link Seam](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=359417).

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but it seems like this would require even more work than conditional compilation. I also lose flexibility. If in one test I need `Dependency` to be a stub, and another where I need it to be a mock, I must create two libraries and link against them.

Comment: Well, you can do whatever you like with the other implementation. Give it a switch to act like a stub or a mock. And yes, dependency breaking is hard work, but the benefits can be liberating.